# Cannot get IBus to Work in 14.04

Tags: ibus

I'm unable to get IBus working in 14.04. The system tray never shows the keyboard icon or the IBus icon, even though "Show icon on system tray" is checked in the IBus preferences dialog. I can hit Ctrl-Space as often as i want, nothing happens. I also tried defining a different shortcut to change languages - to no avail. Finally, I also installed language-selector-gnome, and made sure that IBus is selected as "Keyboard input method system". What else can I try? Thanks!

Comment: I have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I installed ibus through system settings / language support / install remove languages. Ibus will be chosen by default. Then system settings / text entry and select the required language. The new language will be added ans shown in the top notification area

Answer (score 0):

Try running `XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=GNOME ibus-daemon -rd` in your terminal.
If that works, add `bash -c 'XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=GNOME ibus-daemon -rd'` to your startup applications to make it permanent.